# Django: How to dump model defination to json? Or define a model by json?

Tags: django

### Background:

I use mixed webframeworks: `openresty` and `django` over same database. I use django mainly for database schema update and admin site. The best result would be that Django can define a model by some json.

Does Django has anything to handle this? for example, convert:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'log'
```

to its json form, something like:

```
{
"db_table": "log",
"managed": true,
"fields": [
  {"name": "ctime", "type": "datetime","null":true},
  {"name": "message", "type": "char", "maxlength":1024},
],
}
```

Or define a model by json:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        json = {...}
```

Comment: There's nothing built-in to Django that provides this functionality. You could write something to do it? Is this for some API schema?

Comment: I don't know any tool can do that. But you know when we run `python manage.py migrate`, Django will generate a file `0001_initial.py` in folder `migrations` of any app. 
You can create a script then convert it to any format you want.

Comment: I think it's possible to use Django's internal migrations system to produce such results.

Comment: @Iain Shelvington I use mixed webframeworks: openresty and django over same database. I use django mainly for database schema update and admin site. When django changed a model defination, openresty need to know this by loading the json dumped by django.

Comment: What I've done in the past, but it is a bit tricky is to do it the other way around, you define the JSONSchema and make your models dynamically from them, e.g. with a model factory using type(models.Model, {Your schema to django translation}).
It is a bit of work but totally worth it in my opinion if you are willing to stick to django